# Related entities don't save to a database Symfony2

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, entity, entity-relationship

I have a two entity related by many-to-many relation, and form builder with entity field type but all this not saving to the database. Here is links to my files. Can somebody help me. Where is my mistake?

Links:

[tag entity](https://gist.github.com/NovikovViktor/7b3d4e6a36b2f6096b30)

[post entity](https://gist.github.com/NovikovViktor/f5e91c133200f2d90774)

[contorller action](https://gist.github.com/NovikovViktor/a2168dffabfb4b62e988)

[form_builder](https://gist.github.com/NovikovViktor/e0854ed2b22651140e13)

Comment: what does `$this->save($post);` refer to, in your controller action ? There is no save() method in this controller. Or u just forgot to paste it, we can't see it.

Comment: @VaN, this method just call entity manager persit $post and flush it to db.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you dont have to use this foreach() loop in your controller. Form type and request handler should do the job for you. You should fully read this symfony cookbook tutorial : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html It does from A to Z what you're trying to achieve. Actually, what is currently saved in your database ? nothing ? post only ?

Comment: @VaN, only post. Without foreach the same result, relation not saves.

Comment: I think your problem is that you dont cascade persistence. Take a look at the cookbook page I linked above, and search for "Doctrine: Cascading Relations" in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `'by_reference'` to false in your form :

```
->add('tags', 'entity', array(
                    'label' => 'Tags',
                    'class' => 'GeekhubMainBundle:Tag',
                    'property' => 'tagName',
                    'empty_value' => 'Choose a tag',
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => false,
                    'by_reference' => false, // Makes sure that tags 
                                             // are actually added to your post
                    'query_builder' => function (TagRepository $repository) {
                            return $repository->findEnabledTags();
                        }
                )
```

Here's an example of what you're trying to achieve in the Symfony Cookbook : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

And some information about `by_reference` : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference

Answer (score 0):

Change your entities like this :

Tag entity :

```
 /**
 * @param Post $post
 * @return $this
 */
public function addPost(Post $post)
{
    $post->addTag($this);
    $this->posts->add($post);

    return $this;
}
```

Post entity:

```
/**
 * @param Tag $tag
 * @return $this
 */
public function addTag(Tag $tag)
{
    $tag->addPost($this);
    $this->tags->add($tag);

    return $this;
}
```